# How do I send things that aren't strings with sockets? E.g taking a screenshot with the client and sending it to the server

Tags: python, sockets, networking

My client's part of it

```
    agreement_ac = s.recv(4096)
    b = bytes("take a screenshot".encode())
    if b in agreement_ac:
        image = ImageGrab.grab()
```

My server's part:

```
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    cmd_test = input(">>> ")
    if cmd_test == "test":
        c.send("take a screenshot".encode())
```

So currently what my application is doing is that when I start the server and a client connects, if I type in "take a screenshot" then that string will be sent to the client, the client will decode it to understand what it's supposed to do and then its gonna take a screenshot which it does and send it over. I don't understand how I can send it over to the server and save it on the server's device. E.g the client takes the screenshot and sends it to the server and the server saves it on the server's desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server code:

```
import socket               
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
print ("Socket successfully created")
port = 12345               
s.bind(('', port))        
print ("socket binded to %s" %(port))
s.listen(5)     
print ("socket is listening")

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    cmd_test = input(">>> ")
    if cmd_test == "test":
        c.send("take a screenshot".encode())
    temp = c.recv(9000000)
    with open('imgs.png','wb') as f:

        #print(temp)
        f.write(temp)

    c.close()
```

client code:

```
import socket
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
b="take a screenshot"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
port = 12345               
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
#s.sendall(str.encode(b))



agreement_ac = str(s.recv(9000000))
#print(agreement_ac)
if b in agreement_ac:
        image = ImageGrab.grab()
        ImageGrab.grab_to_file('im.png')
        with open('im.png','rb') as f:
            imgsend = f.read()
        s.sendall(imgsend)

#print(image)
s.close()
```

It will save the file on server pc as 'imgs.png'. Do change the byte size according to your need.
Accept if working :)